# Database stop sending data to node server after trying to deploy on heroku. I am just getting A pending promise

Tags: node.js, postgresql, promise

I developed a node app server that get data requested through a postgres (sequelize ORM) which send the data to my react nextjs app when requested.
A few days ago I tried to host the application on heroku, which is when all hell broke loose. the application stopped working. I was getting a socket hangup error. I followed the error stack trace until i think i pinpointed the error on when my server request data from my database. I realized there are no more data coming through. Therefore, I am left hanging with a pending promise. I rebuild my backend. I also went back to previous commit when it was working and the application is still not working. The front-end is working bc it is running on a different host but my backend is not receiving data from my db anymore. I have tried everything i can think of and read a bunch of article on stack overflow and Github but have not figure it out yet. Also, I can no longer seed my seed file for some reason (also return pending promise).
ANY HELP WILL BE REALLY APPRECIATED.

Comment: Hi Morpheus,
Please read the 'how do I ask a question' guide, can you show your code in working state and when it isn't working (if identical just 1 will do).
Basically others may need to reproduce the error to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out what was the problem. My configuration on the server side with my database was not working. Therefore, I was getting an unresolved promise which caused the application to just keep loading while waiting for the data. By changing my config file to this: 
`

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
let database = process.env.DATABASE_URL;
let sequelize = "";

process.env.DATABASE_URL
  ? (sequelize = new Sequelize(database))
  : (sequelize = new Sequelize(database, "postgres", "", {
      dialect: "postgres",
      logging: false,
    }));
```

`module.exports = sequelize;
and adding my postgres database manually on my terminal when running heroku pg:psql to see and create my data base. I was able to make the application work once deployed on Heroku.